# Postgres DB stuck for a short period

Tags: postgresql

My Application has Postgres DB with AIS. I receive events on application whenever a change happens in DB.

We are facing an issue where postgres DB table rows are not decremented, while I receive a deletion event and the event shows "no. of rows affected as 1".

Is there a possibility that DB got stuck?

I cannot open postgres DB as its a live environment

Comment: Missing `commit`?

Comment: Did the xact `ROLLBACK` (or time out, or get an `ERROR` in a later statement) after running the `DELETE`? Personally I think you should be using `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` for event notification, since that's transactional. What makes you think it's "stuck"? Does that mean it later resumes / comes "unstuck??

Comment: When you write "AIS" what exactly do you refer to? I don't see anything obvious with that acronym in a search for "postgres AIS". Do you just mean AIS, the marine automatic identification system, as a data source?

Comment: Well AIS is framework use to notify an event happened in DB and that is sent to our Application.

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes i guess its stuck , because 2 hours later wen i saw the DB, those entries were not present.

Comment: My postgres log does not show any error , so i do not suspect @CraigRinger

Comment: Is AIS some kind of private part of your application, or is it a public project or component? We don't know what it is, where it comes from, or what it does, so it's not very useful to just have the acronym and it doesn't help us help you at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on pg 9.6 you could try `select * from pg_stat_activity where wait_event_type is not null or wait_event is not null`. On older versions you could try `select * from pg_locks where granted is not true`. This will indicate that there are some waiting transactions. If so you could investigate if further.

But I doubt that DB is "stacked". It could be possible in case of deadlock but PostgreSQL can actually find deadlocks very well. So it is quite hard to even simulate it.